# How to find the absolute the coordinates of an html element?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I need to find the absolute coordinates of the html element as per the screen. I know i can use getBoundingClientRect().top and getBoundingClientRect().left method to compute the coordinates as per the view port. How do i find the absolute coordinates? Another question is does window.screenX takes into account url and tab bar into account? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x_axis = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) + element.getBoundingClientRect().left

The above will get the absolute length from the left of the screen.
Similar case can be done for the y axis.

For the conceptual point of view, this picture can be used.[image]

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

Added a special measurement:

```
var offset = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight
```

This is the top of the browser to the bottom of the browser bar (or top of viewport). The new coords called UselessXY takes the height of the browser's bar and adds it to the Y coord. If the browser is resized, then it needs to be refreshed in order to get the new offset. This works best if the browser is maximized.

I made a function that'll display `clientX`, `clientY`, `screenX`, and `screenY`. And `offset` and `uselessXY`
Just click anywhere to get coordinates.

### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>COORDS</title>
<style>
*, *:before, *:after { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; position: relative; }
#display { width: 40ex; height: 50px; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 3px; position: absolute; }
</style>
</head>

<body onmousedown="coords(event)">
<figure id="display" onmouseover="this.style.left = '50%'" onclick="this.style.left = '0'">
<figcaption><u>Coordinates(X,Y)</u></figcaption>
<output id="xy"></output>
</figure>


<script>

function coords(evt) {
 document.getElementById('xy').textContent = "screenXY: " + evt.screenX + ", " + evt.screenY +" | clientXY: " + evt.clientX + ", " + evt.clientY+" | Offset: "+offset+" | UselessXY: "+evt.screenX+", "+(evt.screenY + offset);
}

var offset = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ScreenX coordinates does not take into account the url and the tab bar when computing offsets. I need absolute coordinates from the screen of a html element. This does not answer my question.

Comment: Tab bar is where the tabs are being displayed(MINDSEE) in the picture above. ScreenX gives the coordinates of where the window is being started(tab bar and then following a url bar).

Comment: See update, it will give coordinates as if top of browser is 0.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i find the absolute coordinates?

use [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

Suppose element's id is

```
var d = document.getElementById("socialChange");
var topPos = d.offsetTop;
```

> Another question is does window.screenX takes into account url and tab
>   bar into account?

No, check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX). Area covered by browser's controls are excluded out of the `window.screenX` and `window.screenY`.

Comment: It does not work in chrome. I need a solution that work in chrome as well

Comment: @HassanAbbas it should work in chrome as well, can you share a fiddle?

Comment: You can check this here, https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jKT16qxRhQ. i am trying to get the 'g' element id and then get its offset as you suggested.

Comment: d.offsetTop return always 8, why?

Comment: That could be a default offset of a div element

Comment: but he needs the actual offset form the top,left,right,bottom??? how to find absolute co-ordinates?I am confused?

Comment: @nisar those are the actual coordinates. Unless you specify the top and left as 0 (and position absolute), they are by not 0 by default necessarily.

Comment: @gurvinder372, does it work for the chrome ? I am not able to get the absolute coordinates?

Comment: @HassanAbbas In that fiddle you did get absolute coordinates. Just set the style as `position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px` and then check if you are getting correct coordinates or not.

Comment: @gurvinder372, can you please specify which part of the html element you are referring to set the style as you mentioned. if you can post a screen shot where you set the style will be of great help, or at least mention the element you are referring to?

Comment: @HassanAbbas any element for which you want to know the coordinates. You just need to add this style (maybe vary left and top attribute values) to test if the offsetTop works.

Comment: @gurvinder372     If i add to the body in which my elements are being loaded, it still gives me undefined for the particular 'g' element when i try to fetch the offsetTop property.

Comment: "any element" should be read as any HTMLElement. SVGElements don't have offsetXXX properties. @HassanAbbas, Continue to use elem.getBoundingClientRect(), and combine it with the `outerHeight - innerHeight` offset proposed by zer00ne.